# How to hide admob adverts using Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am adding in-app purchase to my game built on Swift. I do not know objc very much let alone Swift, so this is all a learning experience for me. I have added in app purchases and adverts, now i am trying to confirm the purchase, and then remove the admob ads.

Here is my current view controller:
http://pastebin.com/t5KVvn6H

I am trying to use something like to check if the purchase is complete:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("noAds") {
}
```

What I am wondering is, I put that in the `viewDidLoad`, right? Ok, now the part I need help with, what is the to put inside to hide the ads. I read I can use:

`admobBannerView.removeFromSuperView()` but have on idea how to work with it in syntax or how to create instances. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
// Remove Ads
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("noAds") {
        ADBannerView().removeFromSuperview()
        GADBannerView().removeFromSuperview()
        admobBannerView.removeFromSuperview() <--- gives me error: use of unresolved identifer admobBannerView
    }
```

admobBannerView is being referenced in ViewController. I am really newb.

Answer (score 0):

What Cassandra is saying is correct. You just need to make a

```
  var admobBanner = UIView()
```

at the top of your viewController, with all the other variables you have:

```
var _winSize:CGSize!;

var _isGoingUp:Bool=false;
var _isFirstTap:Bool=true;
var _isInitialJump:Bool=true;
var _isGameOver:Bool=false;

var _jumpNo:Int=0;
var _colorIndex:Int=0;

var _fallVelocity:CGPoint!;
var _jumpVelocity:CGPoint!;
var _lineMoveSpeed:CGPoint!;
```

... etc

Put a variable in there, then in `func createBanner()`:

```
 func createBanner() {
    if (kBanner == .GoogleBanner) {
        var admobBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: isIpad() ? kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait : kGADAdSizeBanner);
        admobBannerView.rootViewController = self;
        admobBannerView.adUnitID = kGoogleBannerAppUnitID;
        admobBannerView.delegate = self;
        self.view.addSubview(admobBannerView);
        var request = GADRequest();
        //request.testDevices = ["600ecccd6a1c2a4750952facf253ea2f"];
        admobBannerView.loadRequest(request);
        admobBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, _winSize.height, _winSize.width, admobBannerView.frame.size.height);

        //**************************************************
        admobBanner = admobBannerView
        //**************************************************

    }
```

Then your remove ads will work, by doing `admobBanner.removeFromSuperview()`, because all you needed was some pointer to refer to the admob banner with.

NOTE: if you try to `admobBanner.removeFromSuperview()` before you have called createBanner(), you will likely get an error

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code, *admobBannerView* only exists within your createBanner func. If you are trying to reference it anywhere else in your code, such as within viewDidLoad, it not going to work - unless you make it an instance variable, just like your _iAdView and others.